# Accessing rightBarButton function from another ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, viewcontroller

I'm trying to access the `rightBarButton` function for showing cart from an another `ViewController`, although I can call that function but it won't display any image i.e cart image

Below code show how am i calling this function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Adding Right Bar Button Item
            let rightBarButton = RightBarButton()
            rightBarButton.addingRightButton()
    }
```

Below code show about the `rightBarButton` function.

```
class RightBarButton {

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard()
    var navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    var navigationController = UINavigationController()

    func addingRightButton() {

        let image = UIImage(named: "cart") 

        let finalImage = resizeImage(image: image!, newWidth: 30)

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = FFBadgedBarButtonItem(image: finalImage, target: self, action: #selector(rightButtonTouched))

        let button = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem as? FFBadgedBarButtonItem

        cartCount { (cartCount) in
            print("Api calling done ...")
            print(cartCount)
            button?.badge = "\(cartCount)"
        }
    }

    @objc func rightButtonTouched() {
        // print("Event Called")
    }

    func cartCount(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        // print("Api calling ...")
    }
}
```

If I add this code inside the `viewDidLoad()` the image will display and the click event work as well.

If you find any solution regarding this code please help!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `navigationItem` in your `RightBarButton` class is not part to of any navigation contoller (as it is manually created and not explicitly attached).

Make the created `FFBadgedBarButtonItem` instance to be accessible to the view controller so you can add it correctly:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Adding Right Bar Button Item
    let rightBarButton = RightBarButton()
    rightBarButton.addingRightButton()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton.badgeBarItem // badgeBarItem is the property exposed to the view controller
}
```

The edited `RightBarButton` class:

```
class RightBarButton {

    var badgeBarItem: FFBadgedBarButtonItem?

    func addingRightButton() {

        let image = UIImage(named: "cart")

        let finalImage = resizeImage(image: image!, newWidth: 30)

        badgeBarItem = FFBadgedBarButtonItem(image: finalImage, target: self, action: #selector(rightButtonTouched))

        cartCount { [weak self] cartCount in
            print("Api calling done ...")
            print(cartCount)
            self?.badgeBarItem?.badge = "\(cartCount)"
        }
    }

    @objc func rightButtonTouched() {
        // print("Event Called")
    }

    func cartCount(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        // print("Api calling ...")
    }
}
```

Comment: Got an error `Value of type 'RightBarButton' has no member 'badgeBarItem'`

Comment: I meant that badgeBarItem is a member declared in RightBarButton which you initialize with the required item. You need to declare it and set it to the created instance of FFBadgedBarButtonItem (see my edited answer)

Comment: Like this `var badgeBarItem = FFBadgedBarButtonItem()` I've initialize inside the RightBarButton but didn't change anything

Comment: I've tried your code and now it display image but it didn't display the number on **cart icon** what to do now ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to retreive an instance of needed `ViewController` with `rightBarButton`, say `neededViewController`. And then you can call it like here:

```
neededViewController.viewDidLoad()
```

or make another method in `neededViewController`'s class with next content:

```
func addRB () {
// let rightBarButton = RightBarButton(image: UIImage(named: "imageName"), landscapeImagePhone: UIImage(named: "imageName"), style: .done, target: self, action: nil)   

   let nc = navigationController
   let navBar = nc?.navigationBar

   let but = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "imageName"), landscapeImagePhone: UIImage(named: "imageName"), style: .done, target: self, action: nil)

// try to create RightBarButton with defined images and a text and pass it instead of `but`
   navBar?.topItem?.setRightBarButton(but, animated: false)
}
```

and call `neededViewController.addRB()`

Comment: Did you receive needed View Controller?

Comment: Yes, it did display the print statement (from rightBarButton function) but didn't show the image same problem.

Comment: Do you mean the `DispatchQueue.main.async` i didn't use it

Comment: yes (or by clicking on some UI (UIButton). If you want to affect to UI, you have to call the code in main thread

Comment: I've tried using `DispatchQueue.main.async` but nothing changes still same output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192464/discussion-between-executioneraxe-and-agisight).